# Syntax error in join expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to update the sched `table` based on the column(Boxc, Sites) value in cutoffnormal.

My Query is:

```
oCm.CommandText = "update (sched join cutoffnormal on sched.Box = cutoffnormal.Boxc and sched.Site=cutoffnormal.Sites) set sched.Cutoff_Time = cutoffnormal.Cutoff"
```

However I am receving the error like "*Syntax error* in Join operation "

Can any one assist on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in access you should use  `inner join` instead `join`

Answer (score 0):

Access SQL does not support the `JOIN` keyword without a qualifier. As you have discovered,

```
... Table1 JOIN Table2 ...
```

will produce a syntax error. You need to use

```
... Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ...
```